# How to randomize sensitve numerical data in Excel while maintaining existing data format(s) for public post? RAND each digit each cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace, format, random

How to randomize sensitve numerical data in Excel while maintaining existing data format(s) for public post? This is to supply Technical Support all information (format, shape ) except confidential content.

IMHO, there should be a RAND formula to execute for each numeric digit as follows:

[image: RAND formula to execute for each numeric digit]

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: based on your linked image, for a 5 digit number use `randbetween(10000,99999)`

Comment: PowerPoint compare do not cover text within image (Financial Spreadsheet with Arial Size 2.5) prompt me to try such as Office Word OCR or Adobe Export to Spreadsheet. Even Adobe Export is less than 100% accurate. Technical Supports unable to replicate my problem, I need to upload info but maintain confidentialality. W/o in-depth understanding what affects OCR accuracy, I either guess worst combination of 6 digit length of financial numerics or use random numerics

Comment: How to determine the sensitve numerical data?